# Mixed Content: The page at 'myUrl' was loaded over HTTPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-vision, mixed-content

i am using flask app to upload and display a picture (after displaying also some image analysis detection with google cloud vision API) but in return i am getting this error "Mixed Content: The page at 'myUrl' was loaded over HTTPS" for the image that i uploaded , so The picture does not want to display

please if anyone can help me

the error :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'myUrl' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'myUrl/_uploads/photos/0b93397fa45180ee219aa69d3957daba_6.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Goggle will not only find the solution to the problem, it also delivers it: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: it's true?, so this problem remains unresolved?

Comment: Did you read the text? It explains the problem and how to diagnose and solve it in many details.

Comment: yes i go through it now , thanks